# Is it possible to leave a field null when using the calendar widget in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm creating and editing data with QGIS, the data is stored in a Spatialite database but I've run into this issue with shapefiles as well.  I have a field I'm storing dates in and I want to use QGIS' calendar widget to populate that field when there is a legitimate value to be stored for that record, otherwise I need the field to stay NULL.  The problem is the widget is populating the field with the current date by default.  There's no way on the data entry form to clear it out and leave the field NULL.  Am I missing something, perhaps a checkbox somewhere?

Comment: Are you using QGIS 2.4? I think someone has asked a similar question relating to this - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104466/how-to-set-null-as-default-value-for-a-date-field-in-qgis-2-4/104471